# BSONError in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, bson, mongodb-compass

I've newly installed the MongoDB Windows Server, Mongosh and MongoDB Compass.
Everytime I try to connect Compass to the my local Server, it throws the following error:

Failed to retrieve server info
BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document

This is very strange because in mongosh the connexion works very well.
I've reinstalled the three named applications two times but the problem remains.

Comment: I've installed MongoDB 6.0 on a Windows 10 machine...